# Auto conversation of type in Bison/Java

Tags: java, bison

I'm working on parser using Bison and Java and I have some issue. I used for default semantic values my own type "TreeNode". It's code from my .y file:

```
prog: def_var TERMINATOR inc_val {
    TreeNode t = new TreeNode();
    t = $1;
}
```

It's code generates by Bison:

```
TreeNode t = new TreeNode();
t = ((Integer)(yystack.valueAt (9-(1))));
```

And I have error "incovertible types", because my TreeNode can't be convert to Integer. How can I disable this auto-convertion?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my typo. Of course, bison doesn't change variable names. But I couldn't understand, why Bison uses generate conversation of types, because I defind my own class by %define stype "TreeNode"

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the code you quote comes from the bison specification you quote, because I don't believe bison changes variable names, even in Java. So you should try to track down the production which actually produces that compile-time error. I suspect you'll find that whatever `b` is being assigned from in that production has type `Integer`.

bison always uses some base type (super type, I guess you'd say) for its Java object stack, which can hold any semantic value from any terminal or token. By default, it uses `Object` but you can define something more restrictive if you want to. So it has to cast the value on the object stack to the known (declared) value of the token or terminal. That's where the `(Integer)` is coming from.